# Piecewise function is onto and one to one but the domain of the inverse overlap?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given this piecewise function defined by:

$f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where\ $f(x) = \begin{cases}
    x-2,& \text{if } x\geq 5\\
    x+1, & \text{if } x\leq 4.\\
\end{cases}.$

Proving it is onto:

$f(x) = y$
$f(y+2) = y$
$f(y-1) = y$
So onto

Proving it is one to one:

$a - 2 = b - 2$, therefore $a = b$

And

$a + 1 = b + 1$

Therefore $a = b$

So onto.

I then compute the inverse and get

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    x+2,& \text{if } x\geq 3\\
    x-1, & \text{if } x\leq 5.\\
\end{cases}
$$

The issue is that the domains overlap which is why I’m confused.
Therefore, it must be that there is no inverse and that the function is actually not bijective but unable to disprove or find a mistake in my work.

Not sure how formatting math works, sorry for the messiness.

Comment: It is not injective! For example, $f(2)=2+1=3=5-2=f(5)$, but $2\neq 5$.

Comment: Note that f(4)=5=f(7), so the function is not really one to one

Comment: Draw the graph. Format mathematics here with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, Write clearly. At one point you say $f(y+1) = f(y)$. What does that mean?

Comment: I would recommend plotting these functions on desmos to figure out if its one-to-one and onto

Comment: To ensure that your question is taken seriously by the community, I would recommend that you fix the formatting. Here is a link to teach yourself how to how to format correctly: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference   simply saying that it is messy is not sufficient, anyone can learn how to format correctly, and it is a necessary skill to be a part of this community

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I’ll definely look at how to improve the post.

Comment: @IAAW, true. What is the mistake I made when trying to show it is one to one? I tried showing it is one to for both cases where x is greater or equal to 5 and for x is less than or equal to 4.

Comment: It's not sufficient to show that each piece is individually one-to-one. In the context of this problem, you also have to show that the images of the two pieces don't overlap. That turns out to be false, since the image of the first piece is $f(x) \geq 3$ and the image of the second piece is $f(x) \leq 5$. Write out a table of $f(x)$ for $x$ between $0$ and $10$ (a bit of overkill, but it shouldn't take long) to see this for yourself. ¶ P.S. Roughly speaking, the **image** of a set under a function is the set of values taken on by the function's output, when given values in the set as input.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the second piece were $f(x) = x-4$, for $x \leq 4$, then the images of the two pieces don't overlap, and the function *is* injective (one-to-one). This illustrates that an analysis of each of the two pieces in isolation is insufficient to determine whether the function is injective or not.